# Template loading with requirejs in an optimizable way

Tags: javascript, templates, requirejs

I'd like to load all my templates for a project with a module, but I'm not sure that the way that I'm doing it (a) will let the code be optimized with r.js and (b) makes sense - basically, I'm concerned that a nested require inside a define() block won't get picked up by the optimizer. Ideally I'd like to have a minified single file which is all the dependencies, including text files if possible, after running r.js.

**template_loader.js**

```
define(["jquery","underscore","icanhaz"],function($,_,ich){


    var template_names = [  
        'test'
    ];

    require([
        'text!templates/test.tpl',
    ],function (){
        for (var i = arguments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ich.addTemplate(template_names[i],arguments[i]);
        };      
    });


});
```

And then in my main app.js:

```
require(['jquery','underscore','backbone','icanhaz','template_loader'],function($,_,Backbone,ich,loader){

    // templates should be available here as ich.template_name()

});
```

The goal is have one place which is handling template resource loading, which are then available to other modules.

Does this seem like a good way of doing it, and if not, what is a better strategy?

Comment: Instead, have you considered loading your modules separately? Say, the module's logic and the template together. This will result in more manageable, and modular code.

Comment: that's fine when a template corresponds to a single module, but for things like UI widgets, or generic building blocks (Rows, buttons etc) it's not so 1:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to load all the modules in one go, you could try something like:

**generic_templates.js**

```
define(function(require){
    var tpl1 = require('text!generic_tpl1');
    var tpl2 = require('text!generic_tpl2');
    // etc

    return {
        tpl1: tpl1,
        tpl2: tpl2
    }
});
```

**app.js**

```
require(['generic_templates'], function(genericTemplates) {

    console.log(genericTemplates.tpl1) // some html

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - it looks interesting, will this allow the templates to be bundled into a minified file by the r.js optimizer?

Comment: Yes, bundled as individual modules, but in one file.